# I want to use \includegraphics but I can't

Tags: graphics

My simplified tex source is as follows:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float}
\newcommand{\aaa}{\includegraphics[width=.15in]{aaa.eps}}
\begin{document}
$\aaa$.
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` to compile your document? In that case, you can't use EPS files directly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: I wouldn't have thought this to work: `\includegraphics` in inline math, but it does. It compiles for me using `latex→dvips`.

Comment: It also does using `pdflatex` btw.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? From the comments they might not be needed to solve the problem for you, but they might be good to have as part of the question to help others find it if they have the same problem. Also, please expand on how it doesn't work: Does it fail to compile or does it just not include the file?